# Best way to store user remember me user sessions and browser history in database with spring security

Tags: spring-security, session-state

I need to store user remember me, not remember me logins and browser history in database. Default spring security class *PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices* using delete queries when session is destroyed, but I want to have history of sessions. I thought to make an extends on this class and store data as I need, but I don't know If this is the best solution to do this.